# Execute function once element is shown

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, luminus

In a `reagent` app created using `luminus` via

```
lein new luminus asdf +cljs
```

**How can I execute a function once an element, say `:div.container` in the snippet below, has been shown?**

```
(defn about-page []
  [:div.container
   [:div.row
    [:div.col-md-12
     "this is the story of asdf... work in progress"]]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just read [the friendly manual](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components) :) and found that the luminus generated app is no different from standard reagent.

Changing above `about-page` function as follows does the trick. `about-page-rendered` is

```
(defn about-page-render []
  [:div.container
   [:div.row
    [:div.col-md-12
     "this is the story of asdf... work in progress"]]])

(defn about-page-rendered []
  (do-what-ever-is-necessary))

(defn about-page []
  (r/create-class {:reagent-render about-page-render
                   :component-did-mount about-page-rendered}))
```